# How to restart node application after exit?

Tags: node.js, forever, nodemon

I want to restart the application every time it crash or exit.

for example I have `app.js`:

```
console.log('app started');

process.on('uncaughtException', error => {

     process.exit(1);  
});
throw 'error';
```

I want every time the application exit something will run it again.

I don't mean to pm2, because I using in development mode.

So to start the application, I use `nodemon`. But it restart the application every time the files are changes, And I need it to do the same when `exit` occurred.

what I except to log is

```
app start
app start
app start
app start
..so on.....
```

Comment: You have to use an external agent like pm2 or forever that starts the program for you and then monitors the process, restarting automatically when the process dies.